# Extracting respective row values with first two strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello All :)  Good day!

I’m trying to achieve something using python with pandas..

This is the csv file, when user inputs 10.50.x.x (example 10.50.155.12) then the code should match the rows of the csv file with first two strings of 10.50 and gives us the output as china..  I’m attaching the code too, I tried several trial and error and then landed here..

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['col1','col2'], sep=',', index_col=[0])
#print(df)

def ipsheet():
    val = input ('Enter the ip address :')
    #out = df.loc[val, 'col2']
    #print (out)
    val1 = val


    val1 = ".".join(val.split(".")[0:2])
    print(val1)

    for row in df.iterrows:
        print(row)
        if row[0].startswith(val1):
            return row[1]

ipsheet()
```

[image]

Comment: Output of the code :

PS C:\PK_LAB\Data_Parsing\Parsing_Pandas> py .\main_job1.py







Enter the ip address :10.50.1.1
10.50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PK_LAB\Data_Parsing\Parsing_Pandas\main_job1.py", line 20, in <module>
    ipsheet()
  File "C:\PK_LAB\Data_Parsing\Parsing_Pandas\main_job1.py", line 15, in ipsheet
    for row in df.iterrows:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
PS C:\PK_LAB\Data_Parsing\Parsing_Pandas>

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: `iterrows` is a method, so you must call it here (append parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame with 2 columns
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['col1','col2'])

def ipsheet():
    val = input ('Enter the ip address :')

    #get first 2 inteegrs with . between
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(^\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
    
    #create dictionary
    d = df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()
    
    #if match get value from dictionary
    return d.get(".".join(val.split(".")[:2]), 'no match')

out = ipsheet()
print (out)
```

EDIT: Solution for match by first 4 parts of ip address, if no match by first 3 and last first 2 parts is:

```
#sample DataFrame
print (df)
             col1             col2
0    10.54.0.0/16            chine
1  10.144.0.10/16            japan
2  10.144.0.11/16   hongkong /a234
3  171.18.48.0/24  australine gwan
4  171.18.49.0/24        india dmk
5  10.54.192.0/23     pakistan mmk
6  171.18.51.0/24     sdwan router
7     10.3.0.0/19      first route
import re

def ipsheet():

    val = input ('Enter the ip address :')

    #find first 4, 3, 2 parts of ip address
    for i in range(4, 1, -1): #[4,3,2]
        v = val.split('.')[:i]

        #extract parts from column col1, if no match created NaNs
        df['col3'] = df['col1'].str.extract(rf'({re.escape(".".join(v))})', expand=False)
        s = ','.join(df.loc[df['col3'].notna(), 'col2'])

        #if found return joined strings from col2 column
        if s:
            return s
        
    #if no match any strings return default string - 'no match'
    else:
        return 'no match'
```

Testing:

```
#171.18.0.0
out = ipsheet()
print (out)
australine gwan,india dmk,sdwan router

#10.144.0.0
out = ipsheet()
print (out)
japan,hongkong /a234

#171.18.51.0
out = ipsheet()
print (out)
sdwan router

#10.10.51.0
out = ipsheet()
print (out)
no match
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, it worked. 
I tried the same in my prod environment, my actual csv is looking like this.. 

10.54.0.0/16 chine
10.144.0.0/16 japan
10.145.0.0/16 hongkong /a234
171.18.48.0/24 australine gwan
171.18.49.0/24 india dmk
10.54.192.0/23 pakistan mmk
171.18.51.0/24  sdwan router
10.3.0.0/19 first route

and so on and on..

if you look at the csv, there will be multiple  entries like 10.54.0.0/16 and 10.54.192.0/23..

so if user enters, 10.54.192.154, it match the three strings and give the output as pakistan mmk, if user input is 10.54.0.154 it should be chine.

Comment: @pravinraj66 - If there is multiple strings use instead `d = df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()` - this code `d = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']).groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(','.join).to_dict()`

Comment: @jazrael thank you for your time in this, I really appreciate it. this code works but it gives the output of all 10.54.x.x entries which starts with 10.54.x.x when user input is, 10.54.192.154..

PS C:\PK_LAB> py .\main_job6.py
Enter the ip address :10.54.192.154
Management,  BB3B IP Allocation,  Iaas-SZ MGMT,  Iaas-Mgmt


10.54.0.0/16 Management
10.144.0.0/16 Shared Services
10.54.192.x Iaas-SZ MGMT
10.54.196-199.x Iaas-Mgmt
171.18.49.0/24 Public Address
171.18.50.0/24  Public Address
171.18.51.0/24  Public Address
18.171.77.22 Japan

Comment: @jazrael : 

If user inputs:  

10.54.12.12 the output matches first two strings and output should be Management  
10.54.192.123 the output matches first three strings and output should be Iaas-SZ MGMT  

I tried with multiple if statements and the code is stuck somewhere, I know this is little bit complicated because of strings in CSV. Appreciate your help

Comment: @pravinraj66 - So what is requirement? Match first 2 parts of IP address? Or first 3 parts, first 4 parts?

Comment: 10.50.x.x        -    India
10.50.192.x    -    UK

if user inputs, 10.50.123.144   then the output should be India

if user inputs, 10.50.192.177   then the output should be UK

Comment: @jezrael, do you understand that? They made the same comment on my answer. ??

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use parentheses after iterrows or you can use itertuples() method

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['col1','col2'], sep=',', index_col=[0])
# print(df)

def ipsheet():
        val = input ('Enter the ip address :')
        out = df.loc[val, 'col2']
        # print (out)
        val1 = val
        val1 = ".".join(val.split(".")[0:2])
        # print(val1)
        # you need to use parentheses after iterrows or you can use itertuples() method
        # for row in df.iterrows():
        for row in df.itertuples():
            # print(row)
                if row[0].startswith(val1):
                        return row[1]

country = ipsheet()
print(country)
```

Comment: Hi @Lakshmanarao Simhadri thank you for the input, I have updated the thread, please do have read when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to iterate some rows and look for a value, Python's standard csv module and its DictReader can do that easily.

Import the csv module and use the DictReader to turn your CSV into a list of dicts.  It looks like your data doesn't have a header, so just tell the DictReader what to label each column with the `fieldnames=` keyword.  I'd also start by factoring out the splitter that returns just the network part of the IP:

```py
import csv

def netpart(x: str) -> str:
    return ".".join(x.split(".")[:2])


val = input("Enter the ip address: ").strip()
np = netpart(val)


with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["IP", "Country"])
    data = list(reader)

for row in data:
    if netpart(row["IP"]) == np:
        print(row["Country"])
```

The data var is just a list of dicts:

> ```py
> [
>    {"IP": "10.10.0.1", "Country": "Columbia"},
>    {"IP": "10.20.0.1", "Country": "Australia"},
>    {"IP": "10.30.0.1", "Country": "Singapore"},
>    ...
> ]
> ```

Comment: Hi @Zach Young thank you for the input, I have updated the thread, please do have read when time permits.

Comment: @pravinraj66, did you try the code in this solution?

Comment: yes I tried it in prod. the output(example) gives all output for strings starting with 10.50.x.x...


10.50.x.x - India 10.50.192.x - UK if user inputs, 10.50.123.144 then the output should be India if user inputs, 10.50.192.177 then the output should be UK